# dynamicComponent Stencil

Tags: handlebars.js, bigcommerce

In my Stencil theme, I am including a few different size charts for products which I intend to include by just changing the path to the size chart document. I found [dynamicComponent](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#dynamiccomponent) in the Stencil docs and I thought I understood the way it worked. In my higher level partial, I am binding the string to component in this way - (product.html)

```
<div class="container" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    {{> components/products/product-view schema=true sizeChart='components/products/size_charts/tshirt.html'}}

    {{#if product.videos.list.length}}
        {{> components/products/videos product.videos}}
    {{/if}}

    {{#if settings.show_product_reviews}}
        {{> components/products/reviews reviews=product.reviews product=product urls=urls}}
    {{/if}}

</div>
```

(product-view.html)

```
{{#if sizeChart}}
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-sizeChart">
    {{dynamicComponent sizeChart}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

Where all I wish to change is the variable sizeChart in future theme maintenance. When the page renders, the place where I wrote the dynamicComponent is blank.

Comment: I haven't used the dynamicComponent helper. I did do something very similar to this recently, but took a different approach using foundation modals to load the different size chart template based on a custom field value.

Comment: I was considering just using the if conditionals on the page-view template but I think there are about 20 or so size charts so I didn't want to junk up that one tab. But I do kind of like your idea so I don't have to create a new custom template for every kind of size chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used if conditionals instead of dynamicComponent. It wasn't what I thought it was.